# Noncompact homology spheres?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Are all homology spheres compact? Are all generalized homology spheres compact? By a homology sphere I mean an $n$-manifold $X$ with same homology as the $n$-sphere. By a generalized homology sphere I mean the same with the assumption "$n$-manifold" replaced by "homology $n$-manifold".

If that helps, assume further that the spaces under consideration are simply connected.

Answer (score 9):

If $M$ is a connected, non-compact $n$-manifold, then $H_i(M;R)=0$ for $i\geq n$. For a proof, see Proposition 3.29 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book.

So, if you are going to have $H_n(M;R)=R$, $M$ had better be compact.

EDIT (to answer about homology $n$-manifolds):

A homology $n$-manifold is a finite dimensional, locally contractible space $X$ whose local homology groups $H_*(X, X-\{x\})$ are the local homology groups for $\mathbb{R}^n$ for every $x\in X$. In particular, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a non-compact homology $n$-manifold.

Comment: Thanks! How about generalized homology spheres?

Comment: I edited to include a response to the second question. Does it help?

Comment: $R^n$ is non-compact but it does not have same homology as the $n$-sphere.

Comment: So, do you want a homology $n$-manifold with the same local homology as $S^n$ or the same (non-local) homology as $S^n$?

Comment: Are you sure that finite dimensional and locally contractible is part of the definition of homology manifold? What notion of dimension is being used here? I vaguely recall that the definition only required $H_i(X,X-x)=H_i(R^n,R^n-0)$ for all $x$, and that most non-manifold examples were not locally compact.

Comment: Same non-local homology, i.e., $H_i(X, X - x) = H_i(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n - \{0\})$ and $H_i(X) = H_i(\mathbb{S}^n)$. And as Paul remarks, I have no further assumptions (except simply-connectedness if needed, though that probably has nothing to do with all of this).

Comment: @Paul: I'm not an expert in homology manifolds, but I think the dimension that is typically used is homological dimension, or cohomological dimension. Maybe this condition and local contractibility (or local compactness) are only used in situations where they are needed and are not part of the general definition. 

Comment: I looked up the math reviews of the Bryant-Ferry-Mio-Weinberger article and they say finite dimensional ANR, but not local contractibility. Perhaps it follows, I'm not sure. I'm also confused by what homological dimension means here: which flavor? perhaps all maps to K(Z,k) are nullhomotopic for k>d?

Comment: @KestutisCesnavicius The proof in Hatcher uses only the local homology, so I believe that this answer covers also your more general case

Answer (score 4):

The top dimensional cohomology of a connected manifold is non-zero if and only if the manifold is compact, so the answer is "yes" for homology spheres.

EDIT: As Mariano remarks below, "compact" should read "compact and orientable".

Comment: iff the manifold is compact *and orientable*, no?

Comment: Yes, thanks!  (So the homology sphere is also orientable.)

Answer (score 1):

By a paper of Martio and Ryazanov, every connected, compact and simply connected homology $n$-sphere is homeomorphic to $S^n$, if $ \ n \geqslant 4$. By the affirmative answer to the Poincaré conjecture, this follows on dimension $3$ as well.